# Como castear un puntero a void para que convierta en un puntero a función sin nombre?

Tags: c, funciones, punteros

En un struct tengo un puntero `void *Punt`.
El campo Modo indica que el puntero lo use como puntero a función.
La función es del tipo char (*)(char).

```
struct {
  void *Punt;
  char Modo;
} Strct;
 
if (((char (*)(char))Strct.Punt)(2)==1) {
   ....
}
```

Donde (2) es el dato char pasado a la función
y el ==1 compara con la salida de la función.
(Puede ser que en este ejemplo me falte algún paréntesis).

Se que se puede hacer pero algo estoy haciendo mal porque no logro que el compilador lo acepte.
Estoy usando codewarrior.

Gracias.

Hago una corrección aunque sigo con problemas para compilarlo.

```
if (((char (*)(char))(2))Strct.Punt)==1) {
   ....
}
```

Para lo que no entiendan de que hablo vean el La sección 5.11 del Libro "El lenguaje de programación C de Kernighan / Richie.
No es exactamente lo mismo pero por ahí anda la cosa. No hay en el libro un ejemplo específico de castear a un puntero void en puntero a función y llamarla.

Comment: Me cuesta entender la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Se solucionó. El error era producido por errores en líneas de código previas que no tenían nada que ver.

La respuesta correcta es lo segundo que escribí:
((char (*)(char))(2))Strct.Punt

Espero que a alguien pueda auxiliar esta experiencia.