# ¿Cómo convertir un puntero a void* en un puntero a función?

Tags: c, punteros, puntero-a-función

Estoy haciendo un array que me almacena todo lo que el usuario pide y le agrega un nombre para poder llamarlo desde la consola:

stack.c:

```c
enum TYPE{INT,FLOAT,FUNCTION,STRING};
struct Array{
    int i;//La cantidad de elemento.
    int max;//La máxima cantidad de elemento que puede tener.
    struct Var* var;
};
struct Var{
    char name[100];//El nombre conque será llamada desde la consola.
    enum TYPE type;//Tipo de variable que será almacenada.
    void* value;//Lo que se almacenará
};
```

main.c:

```c
#include "stack.c"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void mostrar_name_last(struct Array* a);
void main(void){
    struct Array a={2,1,(struct Var*)malloc(sizeof(struct Var)*2) };
    char input[50];
    strcpy(a.var[0].name,"mostrar_name_last");
    a.var[0].type=FUNCTION;
    a.var[0].value=(void*)mostrar_name_last;
    fgets(input,50,stdin);
    if (strcmp(input,a.var[0].name)){
        if (a.var[0].type==FUNCTION)
            (void (*)(struct Array*) )(&a)a.var[0].value;
    }
    free(a.var);
}
void mostrar_name_last(struct Array* a){
    printf(a->var[a->i-1].name);
}
```

La salida debería ser el nombre de la función pero el compilador me arroja otro error:

```
.code.tio.c: In function ‘main’:
.code.tio.c:26:42: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘a’
             (void (*)(struct Array*) )(&a)a.var[0].value;
```

Este intento lo saque de esta forma de hacerlo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/502052/205933

Otro intento que yo hice fue:

```
((void)(struct Array*)a.var[0].value)(&a);
```

Y me arroja:

```
.code.tio.c: In function ‘main’:
.code.tio.c:26:14: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
             ((void)(struct Array*)a.var[0].value)(&a);
             ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/srv/wrappers/c-gcc: line 5: ./.bin.tio: No such file or directory
```

Aquí esta mi intento: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##jZPfatswFMbv8xSHDoYVnDQp9CpNoYxuBEI6Nm9QQiknspIK9MeT5dIs5GH6LH2w7Chy3DjbxXxhm6NP3/fzZ5v3Vpzvdp0P0nBV5QKuSp9L23@6bo@UXJzOnDSrMBOm0pDdf73dTGZZ@nl6d0PnH7NP2eRuln7Pvk1mX7ajDukr7uHGOVxvOkCHNB7k6Px8isDReJljDuQslNDCeNtvRBpfoky/vb5I/W85/KoEFJWgkRdGuLi9Tv2JrgvP6EaddxKaRQ7@hA4MajEfDgYPlHSrwFi9cAK4NcG2FO7tFZRCjTlSaEkhCsNqaRXGpKYF8OtCkEsmCxsAKVbiQgl4d0KlkQtDZnHvs5V54FNV2Di1tbTR0Z4AHmSgLfGjewzAjwpLnxw32wVkByFKk4Q7tjmuYi8DHG8u0mGaHPXDNCpleVLK38Iuj1ZY94IBxTddSVNUfn5JXR2MebFOsE9POh889ANZevYX5xmL8kYXehofPpSTtX0X4z0@gZ1aRfFyJXyZ7GHSy0EavltTZ8glhAfguqjXW3CsbuSgbBM1SKwRhSOJXbbbZm1glnzEmmAbEZ0Q0Z7G2/99gZGuoP/LLxPsXYcIusjesOYnr93uDw)

¿Cómo puedo convertir de puntero a `void*` para puntero a función?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C la conversión de cualquier puntero a `void*` y viceversa es [implícita](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Pointer_conversions). Eso te permite crear una variable con el tipo deseado y seguir sin mayores complicaciones.

Por ejemplo, a la hora de crear el struct puedes hacerlo así:

```
struct Array a = {2, 1, malloc(sizeof(struct Var)*2) };
...
a.var[0].value = mostrar_name_last;
```

Esto también sirve para funciones. Recordemos que los [punteros a funciones](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions) se declaran indicando el tipo de retorno seguido de un `*` y el nombre de la variable entre paréntesis y los parámetros:

```
void funcion(int n){
    ...
}

// De paso lo asignamos
void (*punteroAFuncion)(int) = funcion;
```

En tu código, sería así:

```
void (*punteroAFuncion)(struct Array*) = a.var[0].value;
```

---

Si aún quieres realizar una conversión explícita, hay un pequeño truco para saber el nombre del tipo. Consiste en asignar un valor del tipo que quieres averiguar a una variable de tipo diferente. De modo que al compilarlo en C++ obtengas un error.

Por ejemplo:

```
struct Array{
    int i;//La cantidad de elemento.
    int max;//La máxima cantidad de elemento que puede tener.
};

void mostrar_name_last(struct Array* array){
    ...
}

int main() {
    void* puntero = mostrar_name_last;
}
```

Entonces el compilador te informa el tipo en el error:

```
.code.tio.cpp:13:21: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(Array*)’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
     void* puntero = mostrar_name_last;
```

El tipo es `void (*)(Array*)` en C++. En C es necesario agregar la palabra `struct` antes del tipo. Así que la conversión explícita es:

```
(void (*)(struct Array*)) puntero
```

Nota que es igual a como se declara su respectivo puntero solo que sin el nombre de la variable.

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##bY9RSgMxEIbfc4qhoiTLdos@drXgu3coQzLqwCap2axUSg/jWTzYOmmkVDQvGTLf/PPFLl@snecrDnaYHMH9mB3H7nWj1JjTZDM8poQfBwVyOGTgfrV6QrAYMjt0IDM0kKeQY3eGPO4r5r8@9@z/x@FtIthNJE@ZAqVOHXul3iM78FGWY9oG9LQdcMz6UqYBLJepUrskG59BL3gN19yW3aVYtJVabvhcScv06qhUdeSgDdSQy/hCwwMc4LaFOyhOhShejeiGTClK@49if8K0Pn1AN@a3sjE/o0bfSH7RmOdv).

Comment: Curioso truco .